# What is the algorithm to search an index for multiple values?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, search, indexing

This is actually a real problem I'm working on, but for simplicity, let's pretend I'm Google.

Say the user searches for "nanoscale tupperware". There aren't very many pages with both words... only about 3k. But there are ~2 million pages with "nanoscale" and ~4 million with "tupperware". Still, Google finds the 3k for me in 0.3 seconds.

How does it do it?

The only algorithm I'm aware of is to get the documents for "nanoscale", get the documents for "tupperware", and then do a list merge. But that's O(N + M), or O(5,000,000) which seems a little slow. Particularly if I'm running it on a desktop instead of an uber-fast cluster.

So is that actually what Google is doing, and their speed is due mostly to the fact that they're running this expensive computation on their massive distributed cluster?

Or is there a better algorithm that I'm not aware of? Wikipedia and Google aren't turning up anything for me.

Edit:

Since people seem to be focusing on the Google aspect of my question, I guess I'll restate it in the actual terms.

I have several very large (millions of items) indexes implemented as key/value pairs. Keys are simple words, values are Sets of documents. A common use case is to get the intersection of results on several searches on different indexes: the pain point is getting the intersection of the document sets.

I can re-implement my indexes however I want - it's mostly an academic project at this point.

Comment: There's probably a lot of clever caching involved ...

Comment: I'm sure there is, along with a million other clever optimizations. But I really doubt they're caching the *results* of my search, so I'm still curious - what algorithm are they using to actually obtain the result list?

Comment: Google has indices. Lots of indices. Possibly what it does is grab the pre-generated index for the word 'nanoscale', and then for each page listed, look through a pre-generated sorted list of all the words in that page to see whether 'tupperware' occurs. That part will be massively distributed. It'll cache the result, so that the next time you search the same terms it just grabs the pre-generated "nanoscale tupperware" index. Conceivably Google has pre-generated indices for every possible combination of any 2 of the top 10,000 English words by frequency: it's "only" 100 million lists of pages.

Comment: There aren't actually 3000 matches. It stops at 616 for me: http://www.google.com/search?q=nanoscale+tupperware&start=900&filter=0

Comment: *interesting*.


So Google might be using the simple list merge algorithm after all... only stopping after they find 10 results for a page, and only continuing when I request the next page.

Comment: Sigh... I'm having exact the same problem for my search engine project... My way is to build the reverse indexing on phrase so that you can search term "a b" and "b a" to see how many pages matches. But this way gives a very smaller result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're describing it, you already have an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), with a posting list for each term (the list of documents). I'm not aware of a better solution than merge joining the posting lists for each term, and to the best of my knowledge, that's what fulltext indexing solutions like Lucene do.  There's a couple of obvious optimisations you can make here, though:

1. If you can store your dataset in memory, even distributed across many machines, you can [merge join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_join) the result sets very quickly indeed, compared to what'd be required for a disk seek.
2. The 'naive' merge join algorithm advances one pointer by one position on each non-match, but if your posting lists are themselves indexed, you can do a lot better, by taking the maximum of the individual current values, and seeking in all the other posting lists to the first value greater than or equal to that key - possibly skipping millions of irrelevant results in the process. This has been called a [zig-zag merge join](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16952419/Building-scalable-complex-apps-on-App-Engine).

Answer (score -1):

What you're describing are called [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram).

[Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_search) uses an algorithm called [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) to search and sort the results which is implemented using [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapreduce).

All of these topics have been discussed at length on Stackoverflow in the past. It should be fairly easy to look them up.

This probably doesn't help you a whole bunch since you likely don't have an enormous distributed system to run MapReduce on, but since you didn't really give us any details on what you're trying to [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(search_engine)#Tokenization), it's difficult to suggest something that suited to your problem.

Comment: This is just a bunch of techno-babble. The question has absolutely nothing to do with n-grams, and the link to tokenization is bizarre.